# Animating elements of text-shadow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if there was any way to, using jQuery, animate properties of text-shadow like size or colour.

It's annoying that there aren't individual properties like `text-shadow-color` instead of the statement only being available in combined form.

Answer (score 10):

Might be a little late for this answer, but here it is anyway...

I solved it by implementing a "virtual" css-property to be animated like this

```
$.fx.step.textShadowBlur = function(fx) {
  $(fx.elem).css({textShadow: '0 0 ' + Math.floor(fx.now) + 'px black'});
};

$(el).css({textShadowBlur:20})
    .animate({textShadowBlur:1}, {duration: 1000});
```

This is described in more detail here:
http://usefulthink.com/2010-12/animating-text-shadow-using-jquery

Some other approaches can be found here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/let-s-animate-text-shadow

Comment: Any way to modify this to allow you to specify the color to blur to, too? I'm new to extending jQuery and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using jQuery, you can use the powerful animation capabilities of the UIZE JavaScript Framework. See different elements of multiple text shadows being animated at the same time in the following example...

http://www.uize.com/examples/hover-fader-text-shadow-animation.html

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found that truly worked was creating a `<span>` with the same text as the `<a>` and overlaying it using absolute positioning, negative margins, and .fadeIn()/.fadeOut() or opacity animations.  But even that was glitchy at best because of all the on the fly expanding of elements and the overlay was kind of 'off' looking at best.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using addClass('shadow'), and adding a transition on the element?

Of course this doesn't work in old IE...

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript to parse the CSS property and create a new one

```
var myelement_shadow = $('myelement').css('text-shadow');
```

will give you the property

Use javascript's String functions to work with it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp
and parsefloat('2px') will give you just the 2