# Doesn't work change the css attribute

Tags: jquery

All, Hello! Doesn't work change the css attribute. Help, please!

```
$('#container_logo p').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate(
            {
                text-shadow: "#363535 10px 10px 10px"
            },
            5000);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate(
            {
                text-shadow: "#363535 1px 1px 1px"
            },
            5000);
    });
```

Here is an http://jsfiddle.net/pZnWx/3/

Comment: Object properties that contain `-` must be escaped in JavaScript, That is `text-shadow` is illegal but `"text-shadow"` is ok

Comment: Look at your console. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - ` You needs to use camelCase when you use properties in an object like that, `textShadow`, but I'm not sure if textShadow animates anyway.

Comment: `textShadow` - does not work and in the console is empty, draws only the `HTML` and `BODY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try css

```
#container_logo p {
    -webkit-transition:text-shadow 5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:text-shadow 5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:text-shadow 5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:text-shadow 5s ease-in-out;
    transition:text-shadow 5s ease-in-out;    

    text-shadow:#363535 1px 1px 1px;   
}

#container_logo p:hover {
    text-shadow:#363535 10px 10px 10px;   
}
```

Comment: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578860/jquery-animate-text-shadow-css-property