# Animating text-shadow to fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate text-shadow to fade in and out using the snippet shared here:

[Animating elements of text-shadow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226906/animating-elements-of-text-shadow-with-jquery)

My code is essentially:

```
$.fx.step.textShadowBlur = function(fx) {
    $(fx.elem).css({textShadow: '0 0 ' + Math.floor(fx.now) + 'px white'});
};

$("#seconds").animate({textShadowBlur:20}, {duration: 300, complete: function() { 
    $("#seconds").animate({textShadowBlur:0}, {duration: 300}); 
}});
```

Problem I'm having is that the "fadeout" portion doesn't seem to work. Shadow blur just increases to 20 and then "resets" to 0.

jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ANs92/

Comment: Will it not be wise to achieve the effect via CSS3 instead of JS?

Comment: This effect is triggered on certain events, and basically involves 2 animations (animate to higher blur and subsequent animate to lower blur). I don't see how css3 could facilitate this, then again I'm not 100% up to date on css3 animations.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.alexpeattie.com/projects/animate-textshadow/

Comment: I have not, but it's overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Use JavaScript to add, or remove, a class and use `transition` to animate between the various states of having, or not having, a particular class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the current state of the property you're animating in a property of the element. Otherwise $.animate will assume the property to be 0 every time your animation starts. And animating from 0 to 0 will animate nothing.

This way it will work:

```
$.fx.step.textShadowBlur = function(fx) {
    $(fx.elem)
        .prop('textShadowBlur', fx.now)
        .css({textShadow: '0 0 ' + Math.floor(fx.now) + 'px black'});
};

setInterval(function() {
    $("#seconds").animate({textShadowBlur:20}, {
        duration: 300,
        complete: function() { 
            $("#seconds").animate({textShadowBlur:0}, {duration: 300}); 
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ANs92/16/

Please note: You may get problems when using setInterval:
http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts --> Stacking Calls with setInterval

setInterval does *not* wait for the first call to complete until it issues the next call, so calls may stack up.

Comment: Perfect, thanks LeJared! The setInterval was just to demonstrate the problem, I don't use it in production.