# animated text-shadow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have some keywords in the header of my website.
Every few second I want one of them to glow up with the CSS text-shadow property.

However, JQuery animation doesn't seem to support the CSS text-shadow property very well.

http://jsfiddle.net/VWBsU/: This is kind of the result that I want, but the glow has to fade in and out.

http://jsfiddle.net/VWBsU/1/ With a more common CSS-property, like color, the animation works perfectly, the red color kind of fades in.

http://jsfiddle.net/VWBsU/2/ But the CSS text-shadow property doesn't even appear when trying to animate it.

Does anyone know how to fade in and fade out a text-shadow property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

***JS CODE***

```
var elements = jQuery("#top p").get();
setInterval(function() {
    var element = elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length)];
    $(element).toggleClass('glow').animate({
        textShadow: "rgba(255,255,255,1) 0 0 15px"
    },
    2000,
    function() {
        $(element).toggleClass('glow').animate({
            textShadow: "rgba(255,255,255,1) 0 0 0"
        });
    });
},
2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without jQuery.
Here is the sample.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="top">
  <p id="test1">Fading Text Shadow 1</p>
  <p id="test2">Fading Text Shadow 2</p>
  <p id="test3">Fading Text Shadow 3</p>
  <p id="test4">Fading Text Shadow 4</p>
  <p id="test5">Fading Text Shadow 5</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#top p {
    text-shadow : 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
    /* Set shadow color by rgba() or rgb().
       Also, set alpha channel greater than 0 */
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
onload = function() {
    var randomElm = function() {
        for(var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length); locArr[i];) {
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
        }
        locArr[i] = true;
        fadeInTextShadow(elements[i], i);
        setTimeout(function() { randomElm(); }, 5000);
    },
    fadeInTextShadow = function(elm, n) {
        var tShadow = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm).textShadow;
        if(tShadow && tShadow.match(/rgba?\(([0-9\.%]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.%]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.%]+)(\s*,\s*[0-9\.]+)?\)/)) {
            var r = RegExp.$1, g = RegExp.$2, b = RegExp.$3, a = RegExp.$4 ? RegExp.$4.replace(/^\s*,\s*/, '') * 1 + 0.05 : 0.05, rgba = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + (a < 1 ? a : 1) + ')';
            elm.style.textShadow = tShadow.replace(/rgba?\(.+?\)/, rgba);
            a < 1 ? setTimeout(function() { fadeInTextShadow(elm, n) }, 100) : (a >= 1 && setTimeout(function() { fadeOutTextShadow(elm, n) }, 3000));
        }
    },
    fadeOutTextShadow = function(elm, n) {
        var tShadow = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm).textShadow;
        if(tShadow && tShadow.match(/rgba?\(([0-9\.%]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.%]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.%]+)(\s*,\s*[0-9\.]+)?\)/)) {
            var r = RegExp.$1, g = RegExp.$2, b = RegExp.$3, a = RegExp.$4 ? RegExp.$4.replace(/^\s*,\s*/, '') * 1 - 0.05 : 0.95, rgba = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + (a > 0.05 ? a : 0.05) + ')';
            elm.style.textShadow = tShadow.replace(/rgba?\(.+?\)/, rgba);
            a > 0.05 ? setTimeout(function() { fadeOutTextShadow(elm, n) }, 100) : locArr[n] = false;
        }
    },
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('#top p'),
    locArr = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
        locArr[locArr.length] = false;
    }
    randomElm();
}
```

live example

http://asamuzak.jp/test/textshadow_fade_test

Answer (score 0):

Text-shadow isn't supported by jQuery animation. But it looks like your problem was already solved here: [Animating elements of text-shadow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226906/animating-elements-of-text-shadow-with-jquery)

You have to create the animation yourself, the best way to do so, would be by extending jQuery and creating a custom animation (like in the link above).

Comment: Somebody already pointed me to this plugin http://www.alexpeattie.com/projects/animate-textshadow/